# Streaming large data files using JavaWS in scala

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I am trying to implement a download function in scala to stream large data content. I am able to get it to download but with a long delay because it is being saved to local. I know there are examples in the play framework documentation on how to stream large data content, however, there are no examples in how to use the JavaWS in scala.

In more details...
In my scala code

```
import play.libs.ws_ //note this is not play.api.ws_
...
val url: String = "some large file download link"
val wsRequest = ws.url(url) //ws is WSClient
wsRequest.get().wrapped().map(response => {
  val inputStream = response.getBodyAsStream()
  val dataContent: Enumerator[Array[Byte]] = Enumerator.fromStream(inputStream)
  Ok.chunked(dataContent)
)}
```

there's a long delay when mapping the request (the response is not mapped immediately but rather it has a long delay). So i was wondering if anyone knew what is wrong or if there are any limitation with using JavaWS in scala?

Comment: What's "large" for you? a few MB? GB? TB? And how long is the delay?

Comment: 1GB. It works well for small pdf files, but I potentially want to be able to download video content. The delay is proportional to the size of the file. 200mb gives me a one minute delay